# putting multiple lines on one line using expect script

Tags: tcl, expect

I wrote a expect script to verify if I have static routes on cisco routers. I need that output line appear all on same line, even the variable match multiple lines

The command bellow is for cisco devices:

```
example1#sh run | i ip route
ip route 169.254.0.1 255.255.255.255 Dialer1
ip route 169.254.0.2 255.255.255.255 Dialer2
example1#
```

Here the expect script:

```
set hostname "example1"
set model "cisco1841"

send "sh run \| i ip route\r" ; sleep 5
expect {
    -re {\r\nip\s+route.*} { 
        set route "$expect_out(0,string)"
        set f [open file.csv a]
        puts -nonewline $f $hostname,$model,$route
        puts $f "\r"
        close $f
    }
    timeout { 
        set route "no static route"
        set f [open file.csv a]
        puts -nonewline $f $hostname,$model,$route
        puts $f "\r"
        close $f
    }
}
```

Here the variable $route

```
ip route 169.254.0.1 255.255.255.255 Dialer1
ip route 169.254.0.2 255.255.255.255 Dialer2
example1#
```

Verifying the output file, it's not what I expect. The argument "-nonewline" wont work. The file always does a newline.

Here the output file:

```
example1,cisco1841,ip route 169.254.0.1 255.255.255.255 Dialer1
ip route 169.254.0.2 255.255.255.255 Dialer2
example1#
```

I made a test and the problem is because the variable wont have a '\n\r' on end of lines.

Test - NOK

```
set route "ip route 169.254.0.1 255.255.255.255 Dialer1
ip route 169.254.0.2 255.255.255.255 Dialer2
example1#"
```

Test -  OK

```
set route "ip route 169.254.0.1 255.255.255.255 Dialer1 \
ip route 169.254.0.2 255.255.255.255 Dialer2 \
example1#"
```

Output file OK

```
example1,cisco1841,ip route 169.254.0.1 255.255.255.255 Dialer1 ip route 169.254.0.2 255.255.255.255 Dialer2 example1#
```

How can I to match multiple lines and save the output on same line, for each device, using expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default,`puts` command outputs a newline character after string, but this feature may be suppressed by specifying the `-nonewline` switch. **It will never remove any existing newline character already available in the passed input string**

In your case, the variable `route` already having newline characters embedded int it, thereby causing it to get printed in that manner.

You can either replace all the newline characters with a space in the `route` variable or split them as list and then write it to a file.

```
puts [regsub -all {\n} $route " "]
```

One more observation. You have used `sleep` command after sending some commands.

```
send "sh run \| i ip route\r" ; sleep 5
```

Then you are expecting `\r\nip\s+route.*` which is currently matching your needs. Suppose, if the output is huge or took more time to complete, then it may fail. To have a safe approach, you can use `exp_continue` to match each occurrence of line.